# Why are mutables allowed in F#? When are they essential?

Tags: f#

Coming from C#, trying to get my head around the language.

From what I understand one of the main benefits of F# is that you ditch the concept of state, which should (in many cases) make things much more robust.

If this is the case (and correct me if it's not), why allow us to break this principle with mutables? To me it feels like it they don't belong in the language. I understand you don't have to use them, but it gives you the tools to go off track and think in an OOP manner.

Can anyone provide an example of where a mutable value is essential?

Comment: Interop with C# and other .NET code, optimization etc.

Comment: They're not essential. They are _useful_. F# wasn't designed with minimalism in mind. Many problems are more clearly expressed with mutable variables, notably complicated folds.

Comment: They're essential for F# to be useful. Without those features it would be hard to use F# in production code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Current compilers for declarative (stateless) code are not very smart. This results in lots of memory allocations and copy operations, which are rather expensive. Mutating some property of an object allows to re-use the object in its new state, which is much faster.

**Imagine you make a game** with 10000 units moving around at 60 ticks a second. You can do this in F#, including collisions with a mutable quad- or octree, on a single CPU core.

Now imagine the units and quadtree are immutable. The compiler would have no better idea than to *allocate and construct 600000 units per second and create 60 new trees per second*. And this excludes any changes in other management structures. In a real-world use case with complex units, this kind of solution will be too slow.

F# is a *multi-paradigm language* that enables the programmer to write functional, object-oriented, and, to an extent, imperative programs. Currently, each variant has its valid uses. Maybe, at some point in the future, better compilers will allow for better optimization of declarative programs, but right now, we have to fall back to imperative programming when performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 7):

Having the ability to use mutable state is often important for performance reasons, among other things.

Consider implementing the API `List.take: count : int -> list : 'a list -> 'a list` which returns a list consisting of only the first `count` elements from the input list.

If you are bound by immutability, Lists can only be built up back-to-front. Implementing `take` then boils down to

- Build up result list back-to-front with first `count` guys from input: *O(count)*
- Reverse that result and return *O(count)*

The F# runtime, for performance reasons, has the magic special ability to build Lists front-to-back when needed (i.e. to mutate the tail of the last guy to point to a new tail element).  The basic algorithm used for `List.take` is:

- Build up result list front-to-back with first `count` guys from input: *O(count)*
- Return the result

Same asymptotic performance, but in practical terms it's twice as fast to use mutation in this case.

Pervasive mutable state can be a nightmare as code is difficult to reason about. But if you factor your code so that mutable state is tightly encapsulated (e.g. in implementation details of `List.take`), then you can enjoy its benefits where it makes sense.  So making immutability the default, but still allowing mutability, is a very practical and useful feature of the language.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, what makes F# powerful is, in my opinion, not just the immutability by default, but a whole mix of features like: immutability by default, type inference, lightweight syntax, sum (DUs) and product types (tuples), pattern matching and currying by default. Possibly more.

These make F# very functional by default and they make you program in a certain way. In particular they make you feel uncomfortable when you use mutable state, as it requires the `mutable` keyword. Uncomfortable in this sense means more careful. And that is exactly what you should be.

Mutable state is not forbidden or evil **per se**, but it should be **controlled**. The need to explicitly use `mutable` is like a warning sign making you aware of danger. And good ways how to control it, is using it internally within a function. That way you can have your own internal mutable state and still be perfectly thread-safe because you don't have **shared mutable state**. In fact, your function can still be referentially transparent even if it uses mutable state internally.

As for why F# allows mutable state; it would be very difficult to write usual real-world code without the possibility for it. For instance in Haskell, something like a random number cannot be done in the same way as it can be done in F#, but rather needs threading through the state explicitly.

When I write applications, I tend to have about 95% of the code base in a very functional style that would be pretty much 1:1 portable to say Haskell without any trouble. But then at the system boundaries or at some performance-critical inner loop mutable state is used. That way you get the best of both worlds.